# macOS Sierra installing PHP Extension intl

Tags: php, apache, xampp, macos-sierra, php-extension

I am trying to get magento 2.x to run on my machine. I am using `xampp 5.6` with the same php version and running a virtual apache server.

As seen in this screenshot [image]
The PHP Extension intl. is missing.

I was researching on how it can be added / activated.

I tried uncommenting the extension in the `php.ini` of xampp but it still appears as missing.

I tried to follow this [guide](http://budiirawan.com/install-php-intl-extension-os-x/), but when I try to install intl with

```
sudo pecl install intl
```

it fails with

```
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
make: *** [php_intl.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Comment: Ditch xampp and start working with Homebrew. It'll make life much easier.

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide the intl.so file which doesn't come with XAMPP.

To fix this you just have to follow the steps below.

1. Get the intl.so file (explained below)
2. Copy the intl.so file to /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-[some date]/
3. Add a new line `extension=intl.so` to the end of your php.ini which is usually located at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini
4. Restart Apache Server

Only the first step is different for different users.

You have to get the correct intl.so file.

if you have php 7.0 run `brew install php70-intl`
other versions must be `php71-intl` or `php56-intl`.

Your intl.so can be found in `/usr/local/Cellar/php70-intl/[version]/intl.so`

It should be similar for different php versions.

To copy it : open your terminal

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/php70-intl/[version]/
cp intl.so /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-[some date]/
```

Now add your entry to the php ini file and restart Apache.

Comment: Error: No available formula with the name "php70-intl"